# Where are the rigid body tool buttons in Blender 2.80?

Tags: interface

[image]

Due to changes in 3d view port interface it's hard to find tool shelf menus in Blender 2.80. I do not want a shortcut for the *Rigid Body Tools -> Copy From Active* button, but instead the new position in the 3d view port in 2.80. I want this because I think that keyboard shortcut may be harder to remember than a button position after a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Check this out]

You can either press space to pull up the list of commands you can input and type in rigid body, which will give you the option to copy rigid body settings, or you can follow the instructions on the screenshot.